# Tkinter code using font module can't run from command line?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-idle

I have code using tkinter which I can run from IDLE just fine, but which throws the exception `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'font'` when it is run from the command line. Other tkinter programs work fine, but anything using the tkinter package's font.py gives me this error.

I've checked my python files and c:/Python34/Lib/tkinter/font.py is there. I am not sure why, from the command line, it thinks font is an attribute and not a module of the tkinter package.

Example code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

test_font = tk.font.Font(size=12,weight='bold')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This Q and A inspired https://bugs.python.org/issue25507.  In IDLE for 3.5.3 and 3.6.a4, "import tkinter; tkinter.font' will raise AttributeError.

Comment: My answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806673/importing-from-a-package-in-idle-vs-shell/38808437#38808437 describes how to patch IDLE in existing releases to give the proper error message.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Same here:

```
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import tkinter as tk
 >>> tk.font
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'font'
```

The answer is simple: Python doesn't automagically import all module hierarchies, just because you import the top-level one. Those who do (e.g. `os`, which will make `os.path` available) have to explicitly write code for that.

However, as IDLE uses `tkinter` itself, it has already imported `tkinter.font`, thus you think you can get away without that import. You can't. Just add `import tkinter.font`, and it works.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! I didn't even think about the fact that IDLE would use tkinter. Very good to know. Thanks again!