# Importing from a Package in IDLE vs Shell

Tags: python, python-import, python-idle, python-packaging

Importing a whole package works in IDLE, but not in shell. The following works fine in IDLE:

```
import tkinter as tk
tk.filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

In shell, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'filedialog'
```

I understand that I have to `import tkinter.filedialog` to make this work in shell.

Why the difference between IDLE and shell? How can I make IDLE act like shell? It can be frustrating to have a script working in IDLE, and failing in shell.

I am using Python 3.4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter code using font module can't run from command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877112/tkinter-code-using-font-module-cant-run-from-command-line)

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Yes, that post describes a similar problem. Shouldn't the script environment be isolated from whatever the IDLE uses for its own needs? And also, if I type `tkinter` or `tk` in IDLE, it says `name 'tkinter' is not defined` or `name 'tk' is not defined`, which it should be defined if the explanation in that other post is correct.

Comment: I retracted the close request because you asked not 'why', which you figured out, but 'how to fix'.  I answered that below.  And yes, the script environment *should* be isolated as much as possible.  This is the reason to execute  code in a separate process.  The IDLE doc has a section *3.2. IDLE - console differences* that list some that are inevitable.  I am still working to reduce the number of extra modules in sys.modules to a minimum.  (https://bugs.python.org/issue27534).  The current reduction reduces import time in run.py by 45% for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an IDLE bug which I fixed for future 3.5.3 and 3.6.0a4 releases.  [Tracker issue.](https://bugs.python.org/issue25507)

For an existing 3.5 or 3.4 release, add the following to idlelib/run.py just before the LOCALHOST line.

```
for mod in ('simpledialog', 'messagebox', 'font',
            'dialog', 'filedialog', 'commondialog',
            'colorchooser'):
    delattr(tkinter, mod)
    del sys.modules['tkinter.' + mod]
```

I presume that this will work with earlier 3.x releases, but do not have them installed to test.  For existing 3.6.0a_ releases, replace 'colorchooser' with 'ttk'.

Comment: Terry, thank you for maintaining the IDLE. I really like the idea of an IDE being packaged with a programming language. This makes it easy to deploy on machines you rarely work on. Have you had any luck finding a solution for the CPU usage that I asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551405/python-shell-high-cpu-usage ? I still can't figure out what is the pattern that triggers it, it doesn't happen all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the positive feedback.